# Domain name registrar which provides an api for registration?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

I am looking for a domain name registrar which provides an api for registration.  I want to register domain names programmatically. I don't want registrars which sell packages for resellers or affiliates or merchants where you have to pay some amount upfront or register a minimum number of domains/month. I just want a free use of the api.  Otherwise I will have to do it through clunky screen scraping. I expect to register 0-20 domains/month. The domain registration will be part of an automated web hosting ordering system.

Answer (score 3):

[Wild West Domains](http://www.wildwestdomains.com/gdshop/default.asp) (GoDaddy I think) but it isn't free.  [Enom](http://www.enom.com/resellers/) does it too, which I understand them to be free but I haven't personally used it.

Comment: The SO link no longer exists...

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to fund your account with at least $50 (to be used for purchasing domains), Moniker has an API. Email Don Lyons (firstname AT moniker.com), I'm sure he'll send you the info ASAP.

PS: You may be able to find better APIs and prices elsewhere, but Moniker has a reputation of never losing a domain and bending over backwards to recover stolen domains and such.

Answer (score 1):

Gandi offers this, and has extensive documentation explaining their API here: http://doc.rpc.gandi.net/domain/

You can programmatically register, manage, and transfer domains with their service. No affiliation with them, except as a happy customer.